# LinkedIn auto login script in PHP

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

How can I create a LinkedIn auto-login script using PHP? I hear about LinkedIn API, is an easy step by step tutorial for this?

UPDATE: I want my script to be: Once I open my page, it will automatically log in to LinkedIn.

Comment: try here http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/

Comment: I've been following the tutorial in your link, I got a problem on my $_SERVER variable. It says that the index 'HTTPS' is undefined.

Comment: I trapped the error, right now it says that it fails to retrieve the token. I followed the tutorial correctly, what I did is just to put everything in a directory and input my Secret and API key.

Answer (score 0):

POST your messages to users wall using REST API and obtained token
http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens

Hope this may work.